# What is a GB in this part diagram?

Tags: parts, part-identification

I've been looking at this diagram to try and understand what's what under my hood, and I'm not sure what "GB-1" and "GB-2" and so on are referring to.

[image]

Comment: What vehicle is it, year, model, engine size. It looks like a Suburu.

Comment: Wow, good call. Subaru Legacy '97. 2200.

Comment: @Aerovistae, he's cheating - the Subaru owners in the audience know that they all look the same under the hood ;-)

Comment: I drive a 2 litre Ford Focus, just like the wife suggested. Its the brother-in-law who has a Subaru:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a ground, and as Digital Lightcraft "Ground Bolt" sounds reasonable. The picture below show another view from the same car. You can see from the picture that it is indeed a terminal that's bolted to the chassis.

[image]

Comment: Interesting though, one is called GB-7 while the other is simply GR...

Answer (score 4):

Hard to say without knowing the car, but based on previous experience, its likely to be "Ground Bolt"

IE ground / earth (-) for the electrical system to the chassis/shell/monocoque

Comment: They are in fact on the chassis, I was going for the same guess.